# Can't click any of the accounts or buttons in Windows 7 login screen

Tags: windows-7

I'm facing a weird issue from today. Suddenly my pc got frozen and I did a hard reset. After that it restarted and the account selection screen shown. When I tried to click on a user, nothing happens. Cursor is moving, but can't click.

Then I realized I can change the selection using Tab key and arrows. Thus I selected my user and logged in. Fortunately there was no password for that account. So I logged in and mouse functions fine there. I restarted again, situation is same.i can't click any users or not even the power icons.

Appreciate any ideas or solutions..

Comment: Check the smart data on the hard drive, it may be failing>>>>>https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/

Comment: Sorry, if you don't mind could you please explain a little what is smart data??

Comment: Please google it.